# How to write bosun alerts which handle low traffic volumes

Tags: monitoring, alarm, bosun

If you are writing a bosun alert which is based of a percentage error rate for requests handled by your system, how do you write it in such a way that it handles periods of low traffic.

For example:
If I have an alert which looks back over the last 5 minutes and works out the error rate for requests
`$errorRate = $numberErr/$numberReq` and then triggers an alarm if the errorRate exceeds a predefined threshold `crit = $errorRate > 0.05` this can work quite well so long as every 5 minute period had a sufficiently large number of requests (`$numberReq`).

If the number of requests in a 5 minute period was 10,000 then 501 errors would be required to trigger an alarm. However if the number of requests in a 5 minute period was 100 then only 5 errors would be required to trigger an alarm.

How can I write an alert which handles periods where the number of requests are so low that a small number of errors will equate to a large error rate. I had considered a sliding window of time, rather than a fixed 5 minute period, where the window would increase in size until the number of requests was high enough to give some confidence in the alarm. e.g. increase the time period until the number of requests is 10,000.

I can't find a way to achieve this in bosun, and I don't want to commit to a larger period of time for my alerts because the traffic rate varies so much. A longer period during peak traffic could result in an actual error causing a much larger impact.

Answer (score 0):

I generally pair any percentage and/or historical based alerts with a static threshold.

For example: `crit = numberErr > 100 && $errorRate > 0.05`. That way the percent part doesn't matter unless the number of errors have also crossed some threshold because the entire statement won't be true.

Comment: But that will disable the alarm for large periods of time while the number of requests was too low, rather than increasing the response time.

Comment: @CraigWarren Okay I understand better. The answer isn't immediately obvious to me, maybe by using `crop` and some boolean conditions this can be achieved but would have to play with it.